# How would one put a loot table (of any kind) into a chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[The Wiki states that a block's data, in terms of loot tables, there should be a `LootTable` tag associated with it.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loot_table) After figuring out and running `data get block` on a chest, I've found... nothing of the sort. I even tried to do it on a sunken shipwreck and found nothing. I also found the same section of the Wiki says;

> The loot tables of mobs and containers can be altered with `/entitydata`, `/blockdata`, `/execute store` and `/data merge`.

Seeing as the two former (`entitydata` and `blockdata`) were removed come 17w45b (a 1.13 snapshot), I'm going to assume that this would prove to be outdated. This is also helped by running `data get` on a Zombie and trying to find its loot table (which the Wiki says could be found in `DeathLootTable` tag of a mob), and getting nothing of the sort.

**Without going into the files of the game to find each loot table or some other tedious workaround**, is there any way that I can simply get the loot table in-game then set it using `data modify` or `data merge`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For entities, you can use:

```
/data modify entity @e[type=sheep,limit=1,sort=nearest] DeathLootTable set value "minecraft:entities/spider"
```

and the same goes for blocks:

```
/data modify block <x> <y> <z> LootTable set value "minecraft:chests/village/village_toolsmith"
```

there is a list of all loot tables on the Minecraft wiki: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loot_table#List_of_loot_tables. Just expand the "File structure" section.

Comment: Ah, so the tag exists, but no longer in a "traditional" NBT tag sense like the Wiki says. (Also, completely missed that section.) Thank you! I can't award bounty yet, but I will when I can.

Comment: It is totally a normal NBT tag, just that it doesn't exist anywhere by default (I thought it did for loot chests, but I guess not). There are many tags like that, a lot don't exist if they don't need to. Example: A writeable book has no "`pages`" tag until you start writing into it.